# NotImplementedError: The analyze_document has not been Implemented

Tags: python, pytest, amazon-textract, moto

I'm trying to mock textract using moto

I have lambda_function:

```
from textractcaller.t_call import call_textract, Textract_Features
def lambda_function(event,context)
    s3InputDocPath = "s3://test"
    jsonObject = call_textract(
         input_document = s3InputDocPath,
         features = [Textract_Features.FORMS, Textract_Features.Tables],
         job_done_polling_interval=5,
   )
```

textract.py

```
@pytest.fixtures
def callTextract()
  textract = boto3.client("textract", region_name="us-east-1")
  bucket = "inputBucket"
  textract.analyze_document(
           Document = {"S3Object":{"Bucket":bucket, "Name" = "test_doc.pdf"}},
           FeatureTypes=["TABLES", "FORMS"]
)
```

finally my testfile:
test_lambda_function.py

```
@mock_textract
@mock_s3
def test_lambda_function(event, callTextract, s3_object)
    callTextract()
    s3_object()
    result = lambda_function(event, None)
```

But textract calls are not getting mocked
I'm getting below error

```
NotImplementedError: The analyze_document has not been Implemented
```

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can patch unsupported features like this:

```
import boto3
import botocore
from unittest.mock import patch

orig = botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call

def mock_make_api_call(self, operation_name, kwarg):
    if operation_name == 'AnalyzeDocument':
        # Make whatever changes you expect to happen during this operation
        return {
            "expected": "response",
            "for this": "operation"
        }
    # If we don't want to patch the API call, call the original API
    return orig(self, operation_name, kwarg)


@mock_textract
@mock_s3
def test_lambda_function(event, callTextract, s3_object)

    with patch('botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call', new=mock_make_api_call):
        callTextract()
    s3_object()
    result = lambda_function(event, None)
```

This allows you to completely customize the boto3 behaviour, on a per-method basis.

Taken (and modified to fit your usecase) from the Moto documentation here: http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/services/patching_other_services.html